# Yii2 Advanced Template Calendar Widget: Display events from database

Tags: php, calendar, widget, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using yii2-fullcalendar widget and I used [thiagotalma's post on github](https://github.com/thiagotalma/yii2-talma-fullcalendar-widget#yii2-talma-fullcalendar-widget) as a guide for the installation of the calendar widget. Below is the code that I've used to display the calendar on the page:

```
<?= \talma\widgets\FullCalendar::widget([
        'googleCalendar' => true,  // If the plugin displays a Google    Calendar. Default false
        'loading' => 'Carregando...', // Text for loading alert. Default 'Loading...'
        'config' => [
            // put your options and callbacks here
            // see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/
            'lang' => 'en-ca', // optional, if empty get app language

        ],
    ]); ?>
```

and the above code displays the calendar on the web page. Now, I want to display the events from database but I don't have any idea how to do it. Can anyone help me regarding this matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you read http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ ?

Comment: yes sir, but it's not working for me. I don't how to do in through MVC

Comment: take a loot at the source of this page http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/agenda-views.html you have to create an array with the events that you want shown.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [my calendar view widget](https://github.com/marekpetras/yii2-calendarview-widget), looks like it's bang on. Takes data from your model and puts them into a responsive calendar.

I am the author btw. Should be simple enough if you read through the readme, it's step by step.